# How can I slice every single alphabets in C

Tags: c

Assuming that input strings are

```
hi, user id 5!
```

I am trying to save them in an array like

```
{'h','i',',','u','s','e','r'...}
```

Since there should be no blanks in an array, I have used strtok. Followings are my code

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",input);

char *temp = strtok(input, " ");
char array[50] = {};
int counter = 0;

while(temp != NULL)
{
    printf("%s", temp);
    array[counter] = *temp;
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
    counter += 1;
}

for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", &array[i]);
}
```

Hereby, I found out that my code works, but different from what I have expected. Results were

```
hi, user id 5!
i, user id 5!
, user id 5!
 user id 5!
user id 5!
ser id 5!
(and continues until)
5!
!
```

In other words, array's data are saved in form of

```
{'hi, user id 5!','i, user id 5!',', user id 5!', .... , '5!', '!'}
```

I am not sure the problem's origin. Instead of using strtok, shold I need to find another way?

Comment: I don't think that would be the output of the program at all. Are you sure that's right? Please provide the exact output for the input given. But for starters `printf("%s\n", &array[i]);` is not correct if you are trying to print each character in the array. Should be `printf("%c\n", array[i]);`

Comment: @kaylum I have updated my code as you said and it worked. Is there any documentation that I can refer regarding the difference between ("%s\n", &array[i]) and ("%c\n", array[i])?

Comment: [printf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). But I still don't think your code is correct as shown. It will only store the first letter of each word into `array`. So I don't understand why you say it is correct. Unless your code is different to what is shown. [See here](https://ideone.com/mdb9ln) which is your code with `%c`.

Comment: What are you trying to get? I can't understand.

Comment: JungJaeWon Who or what text suggested an `s` in the `scanf("%[^\n]s",input);` format?